# Free RV dump sites—what's the catch?

Tags: services

According to https://www.rvdumps.com/map-of-rv-dump-stations/ there are four free RV dump sites in Utah southwest of Zion National Park.  Since all four are at commercial businesses, I am a little bit suspicious ([TANSTAAFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch)).  The site doesn't have links for more details.  What's the catch?  Or there really free sewage dumps other than in nat'l/state/local parks?

Comment: Seems from that site that there are hundreds of free ones all over the country.  Which makes me wonder how it's possible for the non-free ones to actually get any business.

Comment: Wait time and location. There's a free one at a freeway rest area near here, on weekends the line can be 2 hours long, a local campground charges $8 to use their dump station -- I'll gladly pay the $8 (or even $20) to avoid waiting in line. I'd also pay if it saves driving far our out of the way.

Comment: What in the world is RV? No, the link does not explain it either.

Comment: @VladimirF: RV="Recreational Vehicle". What in the rest of the world are called caravans or motorhomes.

Comment: @KristvanBesien Mostly motorhomes/camper-vans. Caravans are usually not called RV's. They are just caravans or sometimes campers (camper is also user for camper-van so this can cause confusion). I also have camper-trailer or camping-trailer seen used for a caravan.

Comment: @Tonny language use indeed varies. Often RV is used as a category encompassing all vehicles that are used to stay in and recreate :-). I do know of one caravan manufacturer that has "RV" in its name...

Comment: @KristvanBesien I know it varies. And it gets messy because of that :-) But to me (and to most people I think) a caravan by itself isn't a vehicle. It is a trailer pulled by another vehicle.

Comment: For what it's worth. my half-a-dozen Dutch friends use the word caravan for what USA calls motorhome.

Answer (score 8):

(I can't view the map so I'm not sure of exactly which locations you're referring to, but based on several of the locations in Utah...)

If you look at the list of locations, most of them have one thing in common - they are locations where it would not be unexpected for you to spend money on other things if you were to stop there.

Many of the locations in Utah are gas stations (Shell, Maverick, Sinclair, etc), and it would be sensible to presume that many people would take the opportunity to purchase gas at the same time, or at least items from the gas station store.

Several others are RV parks, where offering such services for free (even for people who aren't staying there) would likely result in additional customers for their park.

The whole point of the "no such thing as a free lunch" saying is the concept that there is at least some benefit obtained by the person giving you the free lunch - and that is certainly the case at most (if not all) of these locations!

Comment: They may also have a contract with the state or the park to do that, to deter people dumping roadside.

Comment: I'm not seeing any to the southeast of Zion, but there are four to the south*west*: three at gas stations, and one at an RV dealership.

Comment: Sorry, those are the four.  I seem to have some mental issue that makes me say the opposite of the direction I intend.  :-)  I will edit!